# OneNote Classbook - Deamon App

Tags: office365, onenote, onenote-api, azure-app-api

I've searched, without luck, for a documentation on how to build a deamon app that automatically creates OneNote Classbooks for Unified Groups in Office365. 
Is there a friendly person who can assist with documentation or answer a simple question.

1. Is it possible to automate OneNote Classbooks for Unified Groups by using Azure App only?

   - I've seen solutions that rely on a user authentication, and this is not acceptable in my solution.

I have tested with Azure App but when I try to list classbooks using this endpoint:
"https://www.onenote.com/api/v1.0/myOrganization/groups/{0}/notes/"

I get the response HTTP ERROR 401. 
This is by using Azure APP authentication ClientId, AppId (secret).

One thing that "worries" me is that I cannot set application permissions for the Azure APP. There is only delegated permissions. But I could be wrong here, but are those not only used when doing Impersoninations?

I hope there is someone out there with some answers or hints. Smiley Happy

best regard
Thomas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well found out I had to build a new native App Azure solution. But things are not just there yet... the API is somewhat disapointing when working with deamon apps and ClassNotebooks. I'll dig deeper into the API. But looks like I can't avoid some hacking and assumptions.